# Unknown Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when running the following code:

```
const int SENSORS = 65;
static float coefficient[SENSORS][6];
const int NUMSUBSYSTEM = 6;
const int ALLSENSORS = SENSORS * NUMSUBSYSTEM;
using namespace std;

int row = 0;
static int outputError = -1; //static to retain value

ifstream equationFile("equation.txt");

static string sensorNameEquation[ALLSENSORS];
static float coefficientOverride[ALLSENSORS][6]; //static to keep large array off stack
static string dependantSensor[ALLSENSORS]; //static to keep large array off stack
static float baseTemp[ALLSENSORS]; //static to keep large array off stack

printf("Total sensors: %d\n", ALLSENSORS);

row = 0;
if(equationFile)
{
    while( equationFile >> 
        sensorNameEquation[row] >> 
        coefficientOverride[row][0] >> coefficientOverride[row][1] >> 
        coefficientOverride[row][2] >> coefficientOverride[row][3] >> 
        coefficient[row][4] >> oefficient[row][5] >> 
        dependantSensor[row] >> baseTemp[row])
    {
        row++;
        printf("sensors: %d\n", row);
    }

    equationFile.close();//done reading from file...close it
}
```

It gets to line 102 of the equation file then seg faults. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: What's in the 102nd line of the equation file? Is it the last line?

Comment: The while loop is probably incrementing row past 389

Comment: Nothing different from any other line. The format of the equation file looks something like this:                                      ECSBSensor56  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
ECSBSensor57  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
ECSBSensor58  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
ECSBSensor59  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
ECSBSensor60  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
ECSBSensor61  0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
for 310 lines

Comment: Run it in the debugger and look at the stack trace.

Comment: The while loop is only getting to line 102...thats what the printf is for....

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the line of the source code, static float coefficient[SENSORS][6]; is defined as [65][6], later you use coefficient[row][4] in the while loop which would be [102][4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're going out the bounds of the coefficient array, looks like it should be declared with the others as static float coefficient[ALLSENSORS][6];

Comment: I changed from SENSORS to ALLSENSORS, and had coefficients array in header file, which I forgot to change....this fixed it, cant believe I didn't catch that....THANKYOU!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your array `coefficient` only has SENSORS (65) elements, yet by row 102 you have read 102 elements into it. (You are incrementing `row` after each row)

You need some way to stop the loop before it has read more than SENSORS elements.